# A closed set contains all of its limit points

Tags: complex-analysis

> ${\bf Hw Exercise}$: Recall that a point $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is a limit point
> of $\Omega$ is $\exists (z_n) \subset \Omega$ and $z_n \neq z$ such
> that $\lim z_n = z $. Now, carefully prove that a given set $F$ is
> closed $\iff$ $F$ contains all its limit points.

### Try:

Suppose $F$ is closed. Let $L = \{ \text{limit points of F}  \}$. We prove that $L \subset F$. pick $z \in L$ and choose $(z_n)$ such that $\lim z_n = z$. Now, if $z \notin F$, then $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus F$ (which is open)  and so we can find $r >0$ such that $D_r(z) \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus F$.

However, since $z_n \to z$, then we can find $N$ so that $|z_n - z| < r $ for all n > N and thus $z_n \in D_r(z) \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus F $ which is a contradiction since $z_n \in F$ therefore, $z \in F$ and we are done.

Conversely, suppose that $L \subset F$, we prove $F$ is closed. We can prove the complement is open. Let $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus F$. Now, how can I construct a ball centered at $z$ contained in $\mathbb{C} \setminus F$? Maybe this is not the right strategy.

Perhaps one can prove: Set F is not closed $\implies$ there at least one one $w \in L$ that that is not in $F$. So, if $F$ is not closed, then its complement is not open. so one can find an $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus F$ such that $\forall r > 0$ $D_r(z) \subset F$. Now, can we construct with this information a sequence that does not converge in $F$? Am I doing this exercise correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last idea can be made to work once you state it correctly. If $F$ is not closed, its complement is not open, so there is a $z\in\Bbb C\setminus F$ such that $D_r(z)\cap F\ne\varnothing$ for each $r>0$. (Clearly we can’t have $D_r(z)\subseteq F$, since $z\in D_r(z)\setminus F$.) In particular, for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is a $u_n\in D_{1/n}(z)\cap F$. Now show that $\langle u_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $z$, and since it’s clear that $u_n\ne z$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, you’re done: $z\in L\setminus F$.

Comment: Prof. Thanks! My forward direction is correct right? 

As for your suggestion. I am kind of confused. Not open doesnt it mean that there is $z$ such that every ball lies outside of it?

Comment: @James: Yes, your forward direction is fine. No, to say that a set $A$ is not open means that there is at least one point $p\in A$ that has no open nbhd contained in $A$; in particular, there is no $r>0$ such that $D_r(p)\subseteq A$. But that does not mean that $D_r(p)$ lies entirely outside of $A$: it just means that every $D_r(p)$ has at least one point that is not in $A$.